# Apple Calendar Time Zone

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, calendar, timezone

This has been an issue on and off over the years, but I have never got a fully working solution.

The problems occur mainly with flights from one time zone to another.

I have a flight for which I enter the start and end times, both local to the airport. However, the destination is in a different time zone.

On my iPhone. I have **Time Zone Overide** turned off, and while in the destination city, I see 2 times for an event’s details: the local time and the time in the origin.

However, I find that:

- The time in the Event List shows only the origin time, not the local time.
- The reminder alerts at the origin time and not the local time.

This applies to other events which were set before the trip.

The question is **What do I need to do to see event times and alerts in the local time?**

To complete the story, I add the event on my iMac and then rely on my iPhone to keep me informed. Latest version of all software.

**Update**

I will be flying overseas in a few months, so I can put my possible solution to the test.

I have set the time zone of the flights to `floating`, which seemed to work when flying interstate earlier.

To be safe, I have also included the local times in the notes section so I can compare; I will also have the original tickets any way. A few years ago I was caught out by the time zone difference, but, fortunately I was early rather than late.

**Update 2**

I have just come back from an overseas holiday, which involved two other time zones and daylight saving.

I can safely say that setting *all* times to `floating` has ensured that all times are local, and everything works as expected.

I have taken to using floating times for all of my travel times, as well as for all of my automated events. What I need to do now is work our how to make it the default for other events.

Comment: To avoid any error, I always put the correct times within the event title, and I define the event limits in local starting time. When I arrive on destination, I switch to destination local time, the event limits change to local time,. The title information is still OK: start time on starting local zone, ending time on destination local time.

Answer (score 6):

I've just given up creating timezoned start and finish times in MacOS Sierra.  But in iOS 10 and iOS 11, you can assign a different timezone to start and finish.  It turns up correct in my linked iCloud calendar & my OSX calendar the right way, showing the correct duration and all.
Time to fix MacOS

Answer (score 2):

In Calendar Advanced Preferences there is an option to turn on Time Zone Support.

This is not a totally satisfactory solution, as the Time Zone applies to the whole event.

When I am flying I enter Departure time in my local Time Zone, and create a separate event for Arrival in the other Time Zone.

Comment: I have taken to entering the local time in the notes section of an event. However, I am experimenting with hand-creating an `ical` event: it appears to allow me to enter different time zones for the start and finish time.

Comment: Apropos Time Zone Support, I notice that you can (a) set a specific time zone for an individual event, and (b) set that time zone to __floating__. When I viewed my calendar in another time zone (by selecting it from the drop down) floating events appeared to display with their original time, not the time-zone adjusted time. I’m not flying out for a while, but this seems to be the solution. If you could verify this and incorporate the results, I could then accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Once again I ran into this problem, and again looked for an [answer](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5152106?answerId=27657472022#27657472022):

The ability to specify start/end times in different time zones is well support in the **iOS** Calendar app, but **not** in **macOS** Calendar. If you enter it on the iOS side, it will then be correctly displayed on the macOS side. That is, on iOS I can enter a calendar item for (say) a flight across time zones, using local airport times. When I look at the item on macOS it says something like “11:47 AM (PDT) to 7:22 PM (EDT)” and the start/end times are as expected

Comment: D'oh! I first misread the comment from “Keith in Oz” — I just repeated what he said.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This issue has been worked on by the microsoft office team and they launched a Dual time zone feature in the new verson (16.11) of outlook.  (FYI you need a Office 365 subscription in order to view it.) https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Outlook-Blog/Outlook-for-Mac-adds-new-time-zone-features-in-Insider-Fast/ba-p/158278

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best.  Answers should be self-contained so others can find them by using the search feature.  Links can change and become outdated so we prefer the answers to not just be a link.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review